# Example count query for Micronaut data @Query

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

Can someone give an example countQuery to implement pagination while doing explicit query (@Query) using Micronaut data? There is no examples at https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#explicitQueries

I have to make a query like the one below

```
@Query("From UserRelation where userId = :userId and itemId=:itemId", countQuery = <count query here>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```java
@Query(
  value = "select relation_ from UserRelation relation_ where relation_.userId = :userId and relation_.itemId = :itemId", 
  countQuery = "select count(relation_) from UserRelation relation_ where relation_.userId = :userId and relation_.itemId = :itemId"
)
```

The count query will be the same only with one change and it is the `count()` function in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was expecting a limit/offset type query there.